# ENC28j60 ethernet interfacing with efm8lb1 help needed

Tags: spi, ethernet, 8051

I am a newbie to ethernet controller. I went through ENC28j60 documentation But I couldn't find a proper example similar to my project.

EFM8LB1 will read some sensor data (for example sensor data 'abcd'). if i want to display this data in How can I do this using ethernet interfacing? At least what are the things I should learn to do this? Can I do this with the Microchip TCP /IP stack?

any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.itead.cc/blog/enc28j60-ethernet-module-and-demo-codes

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I need some more clarification on the programming side ( I am using simplicity ide).any help is appreciated